# Minimizing the lower bound of a convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose $\bf{A}$ is an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $n$ having entries 0s and 1s.

I found that the minimizer of

\begin{align*}
{\bf Q}^* = \text{min}_{\bf Q} \ \text{tr}({\bf AQQ}^{T}{\bf A}^{T}) \ \ \text{s.t.} \ {\bf QA = I}
\end{align*}

is equivalent to 
\begin{align*}
{\bf Q}^{**} = \text{min}_{\bf Q} \ \text{tr}({\bf QQ}^{T}) \ \ \text{s.t.} \ {\bf QA = I}.
\end{align*}

Is it because of objective functions are convex functions of ${\bf Q}$ and $\text{tr}({\bf AQQ}^{T}{\bf A}^{T})$ has a lower bound of $\text{tr}({\bf QQ}^{T})$

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @gerw Why these two minimization problems lead to the same minimizer? Is it because both of the objective functions are convex?

Comment: Since this is a convex quadratic problem with linear constraints, we can use KKT-theory to characterize the solutions of these problems. For both problems, this shows that $Q = (A^\top A)^{-1} \, A^\top$ is the unique minimizer. This argument only needs that the rank of $A$ is $n$. I do not know if there is an easy way to see this.